# How to order a string of numbers by the sum of their digits

Tags: php

I need to output the numbers by order of their sums.

```
    <?php
    $str = '11 11 2004 6 99 43 88 10003';
    function orderWeight($str) {
        $nums = explode(" ", $str);
        $newArray= [];
        foreach($nums as $key => $value){
            $key = array_sum(str_split($value));
            if(array_key_exists($key,$newArray)){
                $key = $key + 0.5;

                $newArray += array($key => $value);
            }else{

                $newArray += array($key => $value);
            }

        }
        ksort($newArray);
        $ans = implode(' ',$newArray);
        print_r($ans);
    }
    echo(orderWeight($str));
```

The result is

> 11 10003 2004 43 88 99

It is sorted correctly but some numbers are overwritten by the keys that match by the sum.

Comment: you are sorting lexical values, i.e. strings, thus 10003 comes before 2004 etc ...

Comment: It helps to understand code when you indent it properly.

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel here. See the description of `usort` on the linked question.

Comment: I cannot post an answer to this question. https://3v4l.org/OfEXL

Answer (score 0):

Floats in keys of array in PHP are truncated to integer. So you get duplicate keys for 2 and 2.5 (both truncate to 2). You need to use string keys instead and then use custom function to compare.

Also you need to change **if** with **while** (you can have more than 2 duplicate values within input string).

Here is code that should works:

```
<?php
$str = '11 11 2004 6 99 43 88 10003';
function orderWeight($str) {
    $nums = explode(" ", $str);
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($nums as $key => $value) {
        $key = array_sum(str_split($value));
        while (array_key_exists((string)$key, $newArray)) {
            $key = $key + 0.001;
        }
        $newArray += [(string)$key => $value];
    }
    uksort($newArray, function ($a, $b) {return $a - $b;});
    $ans = implode(' ', $newArray);
    return $ans;
}
echo orderWeight($str);
```